# How to register a request stub using 80 port with webmock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, port, webmock

I am using [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to stub and set expectations on HTTP requests in Ruby. Also I am using `rspec`.

Here is my `spec/feature/***.rb`'s code:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

# ...
it 'Request third-part API' do
  stub_request(:get, "http://third_part_api_path/api/param=value")
  Net::HTTP.get("http://third_part_api_path", "/api/param=100")
  expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "http://third_part_api_path/api/param=100")
end
```

But after I run my rspec test code, the error was:

```
Failure/Error: Net::HTTP.get(@uri, "/api/param=100”)
 WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://http//third_part_api_path:80/api/param=100 with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

   You can stub this request with the following snippet:

   stub_request(:get, "http://http//third_part_api_path:80/api/param=100”).
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

   registered request stubs:

   stub_request(:get, "http://http//third_part_api_path/api/param=100”)

   ============================================================
```

Comment: you don't need the `http://` bit for `Net::HTTP.get` - just the bare URL http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the protocol: `http://` part of the URL for the `Net::HTTP.get` - just the bare URL

eg

```
Net::HTTP.get("third_part_api_path", "/api/param=100")
```

[Net::HTTP docs](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html)